# How to display dynamic HTML correctly?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have an object called `article` that comes from the backend. It contains `id`, `title` and `description`. The `description` contains HTML data and I want to be parsed as HTML code by browser however, browser treats it as text. So, I am wondering why. And how to ask browser to parse it as HTML?

```
interface BodyComponentProps {
    name: string;
    article: article;
}

class BodyComponent extends React.Component<BodyComponentProps> {

    public render() {
        const art = this.props.article;

        return (
            /* <!-- Main container --> */
            <nav className="level body-container">
                {/* <!-- Left side --> */}
                <div className="level-left">
                    <div className="level-item">
                        <nav className="panel content-block">
                            <p className="panel-heading">{art.title}</p>
                            <div className="panel-block">{art.description}</div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* <!-- Right side --> */}
                <div className="level-right">
                    <div className="level-item sidebar-item">
                        <SidebarPanel title={this.props.name}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: NahjReduxState) => ({
    article: state.content.article,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BodyComponent);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React treats it as text, not HTML, for security reasons. Allowing inserting HTML from the backend means you're opening your site up for cross-site scripting (XSS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
Cross-site scripting (XSS) means that malicious scripts can be injected into your website by other people.

However, if you truly want to do this, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` prop. `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` requires you to pass an object with the key `__html` (notice the double underscore), and the value is the HTML you want to render.

Example:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'First &middot; Second'}} />`

[React dangerouslySetInnerHtml docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)